# Create a repeated panel to dynamically verify service health in Grafana

Tags: grafana, promql

I recently started using Grafana (v9.5.1) with prometheus as data source, and I'm trying to implement a dynamic monitoring dashboard for our service, across multiple environments.

I'm gonna try to simplify our usecase below, these are the metrics we're given and can't really do much about their values/labels. I'm also pretty new with the technology, so please correct me or ask clarifications if I'm not omitting important information.

I already implemented a couple of dynamic variables, that correctly return the values of the `env_type` (e.g. `prod`, `nprd`, `stage`, ...) and the `env_name` (e.g. `eu-prod`, `us-preview`, ...).

We also expose a metric, called `app_state` that I can use to figure out whether the service is healthy.

For instance, with the following, I'm trying to verify that the service is healthy in `eu-prod`, given we expect a count of 5 nodes.

```
count by(env_name)(
    app_state{
        state="healthy",
        env_type="prod",
        env_name="eu-prod", 
        service="our-service"
    }[10m]
) == bool 5
```

Now, I would like to create a repeatable panel/row to dynamically report this information for each `env_name`.

The tricky part is that each `env_name` may have a different count of expected nodes. For instance `eu-prod` expects 5 nodes, but `eu-preview` only expects 2.

Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the expected node count from somewhere, like a key:value map of some sort?

I tried to create a few variables, one for every expected `env_name`, hoping I could do something like

```
count by(env_name)(
    app_state{
        state="healthy",
        env_type="prod",
        env_name="eu-prod", 
        service="our-service", 
    }[10m]
) == bool ${${env_name}_node_count}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace 5 in your query  with:

```
scalar(
  5 * (absent(non_existent{env_name="eu-prod"}) == absent(non_existent{env_name="${env_name}"})) or
  2 * (absent(non_existent{env_name="eu-preview"}) == absent(non_existent{env_name="${env_name}"})) or
  123 * (absent(non_existent{env_name="some-other-env-with-123-expected-apps"}) == absent(non_existent{env_name="${env_name}"})) 
)
```

This query will return value depending on variable.

Please notice, that this solution is completely dynamic, and doesn't store anything outside of query. But, for the same reason, it cannot be managed outside the panel edition.

If you want possibility of managing expected applications count by operations team, consider including metric with value through through scraping. For example utilising textfile metrics, or some analogue, depending on your process.

Comment: This is basically what we ended up using - very clever way to use the `absent` function! The end result is similar to the answer from @mem but a little easier to read! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can define recording rules that produce a "number with labels". The expression would be something like `label_replace(vector(5), "env_name", "eu-prod", "", "")`.

This expression gives you a metric with the label `env_name="eu-prod"` and the value 5. With the recording rule you can give this a name, e.g. `app_service_count`.

You can add more labels by adding more calls to `label_replace`.

And you can have multiple recording rules, one per environment.

Another way is to use a file scraper, for example the textfile collector in node exporter. In that way you have a file with this information.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, how to create a "number with labels". Unfortunately my company doesn't allow me to create recording rules (or even less adding new collectors), and the syntax becomes a little cumbersome if I want to add more labels (by wrapping more `label_replace` commands. But this helped me a lot in seeing how to approach the problem from this angle! Thanks!